# Adding directory trees to an InstallShield Deployment Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installshield

I need to build an MSI package which includes entire directories from the source tree.  We are using InstallShield LE and a Deployment Project in Visual Studio (2013 Proffessional); the answer to ["InstallShield LE - Relative paths to file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390098/installshield-le-relative-paths-to-file) explains very nicely how to deploy **files**, but the gist of it is:

1. Ensure your file is included in your MSBuild Project.
2. Mark your file as with "Build Action == Content" and "Copy to Output Directory"
3. Now it will available to select in the deployment Projects "Source computer's files".

The trouble is (a) I would rather not fiddle with the "Build Action" field for some of the files I want to install and (b) there is no such field for directories (we install them into the MSBuild
bindir using post-build actions and XCOPY).

Comment: From InstallShield's documentation, it appears that what you want is a dynamic link.  Unfortunately, that feature isn't available unless you upgrade from ISLE to a paid version. http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpISXFilesDynamic.htm

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is not a fair answer, and if it was not my own question I would have kept my opinions to myself.  But the answer to any InstallShield question is [**use WiX**](http://wixtoolset.org/).  Spending a day getting WiX going will save you endless pain in InstallShield.